# Add ScrollView to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to add a scroll view to two UIViews inside of one overall UIView. Embedding the scrollview did not work, so I am trying to do it programmatically.

I am trying the following code:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.leftTabView.frame)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 500)
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(leftTabView)
}
```

I am just getting a infinite scroll view and it doesn't actually scroll the content inside of leftTabView.

Here is my storyboard: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nu9ujpfk0gw43k6/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-08%20at%205.15.34%20PM.png?dl=0

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching places between the .addSubview order :
    scrollView.addSubview(leftTabView)
self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

Not sure the order has any meaning. Anyway, I noticed you set the scrollView content size with CGSizeMake(0,500)... Are you sure you want it to be of width 0?! Try changing the width to leftTabView.frame.size.width